# Putting \ as the final character inside quotation marks does not close quotation marks

Tags: r

Basic example:

```
print("\")

Error: unexpected input in:
"print("\")
print("\"
```

R seems to think that the quotation mark isn't closed. For some reason, I have to read a text file that has \ as the separator so I assume any solution to this would work with that. My issue there is the same, `sep = ("\")` gives an error

Comment: Using the backslash is the normal way to include literal `"` in a `"`-delimited string, so that's "expected behavior". Using a single backslash as a field-delimiter in a file seems rather evil, but it can be done: `read.table(text="a\\b\n1\\2", sep="\\", header=TRUE)`

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you include the top few lines from your file into a code block?

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is used to escape other things; to get the literal backslash, you need to double it, `sep = "\\"`.

Some examples:

```r
sep <- "\\"
print(sep)
# [1] "\\"
```

Note that the double-backslash is R's way of giving you a string that can be reused, not that it actually contains both. We can see exactly what it really has by using `cat` (and following with a newline for good measure):

```r
cat(sep, "\n")
# \
```

If we have a file named `data.tab` that contains

```r
a\b
1\2
```

Then we can do:

```r
read.table("data.tab", sep="\\", header=TRUE)
#   a b
# 1 1 2
```